# Define sqlite3 database globally in iphone

Tags: iphone, objective-c, sqlite

Is there a way we can define the sqlite3 database globally. I have searched through a lot of places but most of them have deal with singleton or extern approach to define global variables. I have tried both but in vain. 
I am actually trying to use sqlite3 *database on many files to create,insert or select. I really need to know where and how can I create the global variable.
I am defining my sqlite3 database in appDelegate and checking for open or closed connection of the database. How can I call sqlite3 *database from appdelegate to other viewcontrollers or nsobjects ?

```
   /// AppDelegate.h
   @interface AppDelegate : NSObject <UIApplicationDelegate> {
       sqlite3 *database;
       AppDelegate *delegate;
   }

    /// AppDelegate.m

      -(void)checkAndCreateDatabase_2{

        NSString *databaseName = @"main.sqlite";
        NSArray *documentPaths =NSSearchPathForDirectoriesInDomains(NSDocumentDirectory, NSUserDomainMask, YES);
        NSString *documentsDir = [documentPaths objectAtIndex:0];
        databasePath = [documentsDir stringByAppendingPathComponent:databaseName];

       }
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

```
@interface AppDelegate : NSObject <UIApplicationDelegate> {
   sqlite3 *database;
   //AppDelegate *delegate; // No need to declare this so remove this.
}
@property (nonatomic,retain) sqlite3 *database;

@synthesize database; //Add in AppDelegate.m

//In AnyViewController.m access AppDelegate as follow.
 -(void)viewDidLoad
 {
      AppDelegate *appDelegate = [[UIApplication sharedApplication] delegate];
      sqlite3 *database = [appDelegate database]; //Do whatever you want to do with DB
 }
```

Hope it helps.

Answer (score 1):

Add property to AppDelegate.h

```
@property (nonatomic,readonly) sqlite3 *database;
```

synthesize in AppDelegate.m

```
@synthesize database;
```

and use it in your viewcontollers/nsobjects through this code:

```
sqlite3 *database = [(AppDelegate*)[UIApplication sharedApplication].delegate database];
```

Comment: Gives an error. request for member 'delegate' in something not a structure or union.

Comment: strange... try this: sqlite3 *database = [(AppDelegate\*)[[UIApplication sharedApplication] delegate] database];

Comment: Sorry bro. But this time it gives warning: 'AppDelegate' may not respond to '-delegate'.

Comment: also then throws "unrecognized selector sent to instance". I guess its some different way. have u tried that anytime before ?

Comment: check your Tab_Table_WinAppDelegate class if it contain appDelegate property/method, I suppose it is not related to the question...

Comment: Yeah. the appdelegate class does have the property appdelegate in it.

Answer (score 1):

You better need to implement a separate class for sqlite db creation and for its functions, make a class level method that instantiate an object of that class and use this object in your other controllers to access or modify Databases.